# How to take screenshot of an external webpage's iFrame using PHP?

Tags: php, d3.js, iframe, c3.js, webpage-screenshot

As I am inside a corporate network, I do not want to use any third party website to take screenshot, so I wanted to take screenshot using program(PHP).

I wanted to take a screenshot of a D3 C3 chart which are generated under iFrame.

I tried **html2canvas** to take screenshot, but sadly its not capturing the iFrame, After a research I found html2canvas can not take screenshot for iFrames.

Requirement: 
1. Chart.php - generates charts using D3, C3.
2. Capture.php - should take screenshot of Chart.php's charts & save it.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: try to screenshot iframe url

Comment: Thanks but can you elaborate more.

Comment: the javascript cant manupilate the iframe DOM [may be that can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819557/cant-change-element-from-iframe-generated-by-chrome-extension)

Comment: @MohamedElHadiMsaid: Yes, that's the problem, you know any alternatives? Still finding a way to take screenshot of an iFrame.